# How to add my own item to system status bar in android near WiFi, Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-studio, statusbar

I seen that the third party apps can add there own items to system status bar near WiFi, Bluetooth,etc.You can see by Google Files app.When you install this app u will get an item (Storage icon) in status bar.Like this :

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can call Google a third-party, when it comes to Android apps.

Comment: No Sukhi Google Files is third party app you can download and install in any mobile.

Comment: Search "quick settings tile" for info on how to do this

Comment: Thanks Bro Ryan M